# Run nested cloudformation stack as another role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I'm trying to build a cloudformation template that will deploy an EKS cluster, nodegroup and workload.

Using the following [lambda layer](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-layer-kubectl), I've created a function that can interact with the EKS cluster; however, this only works if the function assumes the role of the user that created the cluster.

One issue I've found with this is that it isn't possible to assume the role of an SSO user in an SSO environment as AWS manages the trust policy.
If I assume another role before creating the cluster and let lambda assume that role, the function works.

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to pass in a specific role to be used to create the cluster, [RoleArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-eks-cluster.html) only provides permission for the control plane to interact with other AWS services.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to create a nested stack structure what would do something like this?

1. In the main stack create a role
2. Then call a nested template **assuming the new role**
3. In the child stack a EKS cluster would be created
4. In the main stack a lambda function would be created and invoked

Is this technically possible?

For reference this is what the function is currently doing.

```
def update_kubeconfig(clusterName, role):
  runCmd("aws eks update-kubeconfig --name {} --kubeconfig /tmp/kubeconfig --role-arn {}".format(clusterName, role))
def getPods():
  runCmd("kubectl get pod --kubeconfig /tmp/kubeconfig")

update_kubeconfig('eks-cluster-1', 'arn:aws:iam::3088564456:role/cluster-admin')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to workaround this issue by creating and invoking a lambda function in the main stack which created a child stack after assuming the role of the eks cluster admin.

To avoid creating IAM roles in the child stack I created all of these in the main stack and then passed the ARNs into the child stack.

I hope this might be useful to someone else should they need to do something similar

Main Stack

```
  EKSClusterRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - eks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy'
DeployCloudformationStackLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AllowRolePassAndCF
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                  - 'iam:PassRole'
                  - 'iam:GetRole'
                  - 'cloudformation:CreateStack'
                  - 'cloudformation:CreateChangeSet'
                  - 'eks:DescribeCluster'
                Resource: '*'
EKSClusterAdminRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt DeployCloudformationStackLambdaRole.Arn
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: RunKubeCtlCommands
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'eks:*'
                  - 'cloudformation:CreateStack'
                  - 'cloudformation:CreateChangeSet'
                  - 'serverlessrepo:CreateCloudFormationTemplate'
                  - 'serverlessrepo:GetCloudFormationTemplate'
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - 'lambda:PublishLayerVersion'
                  - 'lambda:CreateFunction'
                  - 'lambda:GetLayerVersion'
                  - 'lambda:GetFunction'
                  - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                  - 'lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'iam:PassRole'
                  - 'iam:GetRole'
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt EKSClusterRole.Arn
                  - !GetAtt DeployCloudformationStackLambdaRole.Arn
  TriggerStack:
    Type: "Custom::TriggerStack"
    DependsOn: DeployCloudformationStack
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt DeployCloudformationStack.Arn
      cfStackName: "eksDeploy"
      assumeRoleARN: !GetAtt EKSClusterAdminRole.Arn
      templateUrl: !Sub 'https://test-${AWS::Region}-public-lambda.s3.amazonaws.com/DeployEKS.yml'
      stackParameters: 
        - ParameterKey: EksClusterName
          ParameterValue: "test-cluster"
        - ParameterKey: EksClusterRole
          ParameterValue: !GetAtt EKSClusterRole.Arn
        - ParameterKey: EksSubnets
          ParameterValue: "subnet-256faaf,subnet-6e205960"
        - ParameterKey: EksClusterAdminRole
          ParameterValue: !GetAtt EKSClusterAdminRole.Arn
        - ParameterKey: KubeLambdaRole
          ParameterValue: !GetAtt DeployCloudformationStackLambdaRole.Arn
  DeployCloudformationStack:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Deploy cloudformation stack
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: !GetAtt DeployCloudformationStackLambdaRole.Arn
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import cfnresponse
          import json, os, boto3, logging
          from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
            payload = ""
            result = cfnresponse.SUCCESS
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            try:
             if event['RequestType'] == 'Create':
               payload = deployStack(event['ResourceProperties'])
            except ClientError as e:
             logger.error('Error: %s', e)
             result = cfnresponse.FAILED   
            cfnresponse.send(event, context, result, payload)
          
          def deployStack(input):
              
              sts = boto3.client('sts').assume_role(RoleArn=input['assumeRoleARN'],RoleSessionName="lambda_assume_role")
              
              client = boto3.client('cloudformation',
                  aws_access_key_id=sts['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                  aws_secret_access_key=sts['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                  aws_session_token=sts['Credentials']['SessionToken']
              )
              response = client.create_stack(StackName=input['cfStackName'], TemplateURL=input['templateUrl'],Parameters=input['stackParameters'], TimeoutInMinutes=60, Capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM','CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM','CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND'])
```

Child Stack

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Parameters:
  KubeLambdaRole:
    Default: arn:*
    Type: String
  EksClusterRole:
    Default: arn:*
    Type: String
  EksSubnets:
    Description: Subnet IDs
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  EksClusterName:
    Default: pebble-oceans
    Type: String
  EksClusterAdminRole:
    Default: arn:*
    Type: String
Resources:
  KubeCtlLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Parameters: 
        LayerName: kubelayer
      Location:
        ApplicationId: arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:903779448426:applications/lambda-layer-kubectl
        SemanticVersion: 2.0.0
  EKS:
    Type: 'AWS::EKS::Cluster'
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref EksClusterName
      Version: '1.19'
      RoleArn: !Ref EksClusterRole
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SubnetIds: !Ref EksSubnets
  TriggerKubectl:
    Type: "Custom::TriggerKubectl"
    DependsOn: 
    -  KubeLambda
    -  EKS
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt KubeLambda.Arn
      clusterName: !Ref EksClusterName
      roleArn: !Ref EksClusterAdminRole
      region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
  KubeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Copies images into ECR
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Layers: 
        - !GetAtt KubeCtlLayer.Outputs.LayerVersionArn
      Role: !Ref KubeLambdaRole
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 300
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import cfnresponse
          import json, os, boto3, logging
          from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
          from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
          
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
            payload = ""
            result = cfnresponse.SUCCESS
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            try:
             if event['RequestType'] == 'Create':
               clusterName=event['ResourceProperties']['clusterName']
               roleArn=cluster=event['ResourceProperties']['roleArn']
               region=cluster=event['ResourceProperties']['region']
               update_kubeconfig(clusterName, region, roleArn)
               payload = getPods()
            except ClientError as e:
             logger.error('Error: %s', e)
             result = cfnresponse.FAILED   
            cfnresponse.send(event, context, result, payload)
          
          def update_kubeconfig(clusterName, region, role):
            runCmd("aws eks update-kubeconfig --name {} --region {} --role-arn {} --kubeconfig /tmp/kubeconfig".format(clusterName, region, role))
          
          def getPods():
            runCmd("kubectl get pod --kubeconfig /tmp/kubeconfig")
          
          def runCmd(cmd):
            my_env = os.environ.copy()
            my_env["PATH"] = my_env["PATH"] + ":/opt/awscli:/opt/kubectl"
            p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True, env=my_env)
            output = p.stdout.read()
            print output
```